# Can the UIBarButtonSystemItemDone be used outside the scope of a UINavigationItem?

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I would like to add a UIBarButton of style UIBarButtonSystemItemDone to a UIView, instead of setting it as a property of a UINavigationItem.

I present a modalViewController that has a top-bar view that looks like a navigationBar, I need for the user to have a way to dismiss the modalViewController. It would be practical to add a, well known, "Done" button there, and save me a trip to photoshop to try and build my own.

**Can this be done in a way that does not break SDK guidelines/best practice?**

Comment: hey i am trying to do the same thing but i cannot get it to work. How did you solve?

Comment: Yes, as NWCoder says below. I put a UIToolBar in my modalViewController and skinned it to look like my UINavigationBar, then, using IB, I just dragged the button there and selected the Done button type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UIToolBar is the container for UIBarButtonItem(s), you can use these to house the UIBarButtonSystemItemDone style buttons anywhere you like.